# Floating unordered list- works on jfiddle not in browser (tried updated chrome and firefox)

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

I need to float an unordered list. The problem: I can't.  I found  a jfiddle that does exactly what I need (the coder made a list align its side with some text above it)

Here is the updated jfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/8qzygaog/

Here is the doc I made to test it that doesn't work. (the list goes somewhere else other than to the spot it is supposed to float to)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

 #footer-left { float:left; width:17em; border:0; border-top:1px dotted     #333; text-align:left; margin:0; padding:1.25em 0; }
.profile { width:1em; height:1em; margin-left:0.3em; }
#footer-left p { display:inline; font-size:.75em; color:#666; }
#footer-left ul { display:inline; margin:0; padding:0; float:left;}
#profiles li {  list-style:none; float:left; }

</style>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
<meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="footer-left">
<p>E-mail me at mail@alexbrunner.com<br />or visit my profiles at <ul id="profiles">
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/alexbrunner" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icons/16/facebook_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/109422064867262895187/about" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icons/16/googleplus_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Google plus" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.xing.com/profile/Alex_Brunner7" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icons/16/xing_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Xing" /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://at.linkedin.com/in/abrunner/en" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icons/16/linkedin_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Linkedin" /></a></li>
</ul></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ARGGG

Comment: Maybe a typo ? you used `footer-left` instead of `footer-right`.

Comment: Unfortunately you're a little unclear on the intend layout of your unordered list and other elements. Perhaps provided a simple diagram of what you're intended result should look like. Also, I don't think `<ul>` is permitted content for a `<p>`.

Comment: Also a `<ul>` element cannot be inside a `<p>` element. You will want to fix that as well.

Comment: I corrected that, still doesn't work. I updated the code above with a left-handed version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.

Firstly, you are referring to `#footer-right` when the HTML refers to `#footer-left`.

Then your HTML is invalid as a paragraph `p` cannot contain a list `ul`.

Then it's a matter of removing floats and using `inline-block` in it's place.

```css
 #footer-left {
   float: left;
   width: 17em;
   border: 0;
   border: 1px dotted #333;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 1.25em 0;
   overflow: auto;
 }
 .profile {
   width: 1em;
   height: 1em;
   margin-left: 0.3em;
 }
 #footer-left p {
   display: inline;
   font-size: .75em;
   color: #666;
 }
 #footer-left ul {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 #profiles li {
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="footer-left">
  <p>E-mail me at mail@alexbrunner.com
    <br />or visit my profiles at</p>
  <ul id="profiles">
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/alexbrunner" target="_blank">
        <img src="../images/icons/16/facebook_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Facebook" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/109422064867262895187/about" target="_blank">
        <img src="../images/icons/16/googleplus_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Google plus" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.xing.com/profile/Alex_Brunner7" target="_blank">
        <img src="../images/icons/16/xing_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Xing" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://at.linkedin.com/in/abrunner/en" target="_blank">
        <img src="../images/icons/16/linkedin_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Linkedin" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been working all night, thanks for breaking that down. It works in my browser now. Hopefully I'll adapt it without bungling it again.